# Which points of a cubic are the single intersection between that cubic and a conic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm having problems with this exercise:

> For which points $P\in C$ ($C$ is a non-singular cubic) there exists a non-singular conic $Q$ with $C\cap Q = P$?

Maybe we can use Pappus' theorem or some other application of Noether's theorem?

Any ideas?

Comment: To help people who might like to think about your question, can you give us some context? In particular, where is this exercise taken from?

Comment: Fulton's book, algebraic curves.